# Postgresql to Oracle Sql for timezone

Tags: oracle, postgresql

I have a sql running on Postgresql as follows:

```
select *
 from table1
where ts >= '2016-12-08 23:01:48 CST'::timestamp with timezone
```

Where the datetime value will be given by the user.
I need to run this query in Oracle as well, but I am finding it hard to find an exact function in Oracle.

I tried the following in Oracle 12c:

```
select to_timestamp_tz('2016-12-08 23:01:48','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as c FROM dual;
```

But its giving result as:

> 12/08/2016 23:01:48  GMT-06:00

Any advice, please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must include the timezone region in your timestamp, for example like this:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2016-12-08 23:01:48 CST','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss TZR') AS c 
FROM dual;
```

or you can also write

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-12-08 23:01:48','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AT TIME ZONE 'CST' AS c 
FROM dual;
```

Comment: But it's giving me output:
12/08/2016 23:01:48  GMT

Comment: Are you sure? I get `08.12.2016 23:01:48.000000000 -06:00` for both queries.

Comment: Yes. And that's the issue I am facing from morning :(
I am using Oracle 12.1

Comment: Actually `GMT-06:00` is equal to `-06:00` or `CST`. Check your `NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT` settings: https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db121/REFRN/refrn10132.htm#REFRN10132 and https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#sthref375